# Azure DevOps Pipelines - Relating two pipeline configuration files

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, yaml, azure-pipelines, continuous-delivery

## Scenario

I have two pipelines:

- **Pipeline A** builds an artifact called **artifact A**
- **Pipeline B** builds an artifact called **artifact B**

The following is true about the relationship between these pipelines

- Both pipelines have independent YAML files which trigger off commits to the master branch that affects one or more files associated with the pipeline
- Both pipelines *share some of the same source files* and therefore it's possible that a single commit could trigger both pipelines
- **Pipeline B** is dependent on **artifact A** and therefore should always yield and wait for **Pipeline A** in cases where both pipelines are triggered

## Question

Is it possible to establish a relationship between **Pipeline A** and **Pipeline B** such that they can be triggered independently and yet, if they are both triggered at the same time, **Pipeline B** always waits for **Pipeline A** to finish?

Answer (score 0):

You may try to create another two pipelines:

1. Exclude same source files [path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#paths) in Pipeline A and Pipeline B.
2. Create Pipeline C and Pipeline D with the same steps as Pipeline A and Pipeline B, you could use [Template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops) for the steps.
3. Set trigger and include same source files path in Pipeline C.
4. Set [Pipeline trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/pipeline-triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) in Pipeline D. When Pipeline C completes, it will trigger Pipeline D.

Comment: Have you checked my reply? Is it helpful?